# How do I rename the boot drive on a mac

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I've accidentally (while resolving another issue) named my mac boot drive `./Home 1`, or `.:Home 1` as it appears in /Volumes.

```
paul-reinheimers-mac-pro:Volumes paulreinheimer$ ls -als
total 16
0 drwxrwxrwt@   9 paulreinheimer  admin    306 15 Nov 14:50 .
0 drwxrwxr-t   44 root            admin   1564 15 Nov 14:51 ..
8 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root            admin      1 15 Nov 14:50 .:Home 1 -> /
0 drwxrwxr-x   13 paulreinheimer  staff    510  5 Oct 09:34 Drobo
0 drwxrwxr-x+  74 paulreinheimer  staff   2584 15 Nov 14:50 Home
```

This is incredibly inconvenient as I'm no longer able to click on the disk in the devices list in finder, and also a rather stupid name. How can I rename this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `diskutil`.

```
diskutil rename /Volumes/oldname newname
```

… or even for your boot disk, the shorthand:

```
diskutil rename / newname
```

Comment: Thanks!I think I was stuck thinking it was going to be super complicated because of the boot drive + weird name stuff. Seriously, thanks.

Comment: Not a thing! In fact, it's just a name, and you can even rename it without elevated privileges, so there's not much to screw up here :)